# Jmeter not able to record secondary window

Tags: jmeter

I'm unable to record secondary Browser window using JMeter. The window displays 404 error message.

Jmeter recording works find on primary browser, however when i enter a screen name(Java applet) and hit enter a secondary pop up window opens up and it displays 404 page not found. T[image]his happens only during JMeter recording.

Comment: Did you configure proxy for applet as well? e.g. like described here: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml

Comment: @KirilS.yes i did